# Redirect http://domain/artifactory to http://localhost:8081/artifactory

Tags: http, apache2, artifactory

We recently moved our web server from one machine to another. The web server is running Artifactory 2.6.1 repository on my web-server which is accessible from port 8081. I would like to redirect requests made to http://domain/artifactory to http://localhost:8081/artifactory. I tried to achieve this by creating a reverse proxy using apache2 but failed. If you could direct me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to follow https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Apache+HTTP+Server ?

You'll have to configure the ajp connector on your tomcat's server.xml and add a virtualhost in your apache configuration with mod_proxy_ajp

EDIT:

Since you're using Jetty instead of tomcat, Jetty recommends using http proxy instead of ajp. 
Following this to configure Jetty and Apache: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_mod_proxy

Comment: Yes I did, but couldn't get it work. Also the artifactory version we are running uses Jetty, not Tomcat.

Comment: Jetty recommends using http proxy instead of ajp. Try following this : https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_mod_proxy
If it is still not working please expose your apache virtualhost configuration and jetty configuration ($JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty.xml)  as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it works as expected. If you add the new link to your answer, I will accept your answer.